# My model is not learning, text classification with LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

My data can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/53ii1gpm155f1x8/AADoYZk3cQt5Zw7tfuSV6kZBa?dl=0

The `DataFram` is about (I have 3 writers and text belong to them)

The task that I am doing is: sentiment analysis with `LSTM` layer, which means in the end I want to test the model on unseen data and it tells me that the text belongs to which writers.

I am working on this for many hours and hours, but in the end, my model accuracy does not change with the number of epcho.

as I am new to deep learning, I don't know where I went wrong.
and what else I can do to increase the accuracy?

can anyone help me please?

So the code is like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from tqdm import tqdm
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM, GRU
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn import preprocessing, decomposition, model_selection, metrics, pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from keras.layers import GlobalMaxPooling1D, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Bidirectional, SpatialDropout1D
from keras.preprocessing import sequence, text
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('English')


traincleaned=pd.read_csv('../input/dataclean/data.csv')

traincleaned.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1,inplace=True)  
traincleaned[:3]

data_list=train_sentence.clean_text.apply(str).tolist()
test_list=evalu.clean_text.apply(str).tolist()


X = traincleaned.clean_text
Y = traincleaned.author

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1000)
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)


# transform labels into numbers

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labels2numbers = LabelEncoder()
y_train = labels2numbers.fit_transform(y_train)
y_val = labels2numbers.fit_transform(y_test)

print(y_train.shape)

#Converts a class vector (integers) to binary class matrix.

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded1 = label_encoder.fit_transform(y_train)
integer_encoded2 = labels2numbers.fit_transform(y_test)


le_name_mapping = dict(zip(label_encoder.transform(label_encoder.classes_),label_encoder.classes_))
print("Label Encoding Classes as ")
print(le_name_mapping)

y_train=np_utils.to_categorical(integer_encoded1,num_classes=3)
y_val=np_utils.to_categorical(integer_encoded2,num_classes=3)
print("One Hot Encoded class shape ")
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_train[0])



X_train0 = X_train.values.astype(str)
#y_train = df0_train['sentiment'].values

X_val0 = X_test.values.astype(str)
#y_val = df0_val['sentiment'].values
print('df_train shape: {}'.format(df0_train.shape))
print('df_val shape: {}'.format(df0_val.shape))





from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences    
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=20000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train0)
X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train0)
X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_val0)
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1  # Adding 1 because of reserved 0 index
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
maxlen = 300
padded_sequence_train = pad_sequences(X_train, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
padded_sequence_test = pad_sequences(X_test, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
print(vocab_size)
print(X_train[2])
print(X_train0[2])



#find the max lenght of sentecnce for padding
maxlen = train_sentence.clean_text.str.len().max()
maxlen



from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM,Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SpatialDropout1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding

embedding_vector_length = 50

model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_vector_length,     
                                         input_length=300) )

model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(30, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', 
                           metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())


history = model.fit(padded_sequence_train, y_train,validation_data=(padded_sequence_test, y_val),epochs=20,batch_size=70)
```

The model summery is as below:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_17 (Embedding)     (None, 300, 50)           881900    
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_16 (Spatia (None, 300, 50)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_17 (LSTM)               (None, 30)                9720      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_16 (Dropout)         (None, 30)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 93        
=================================================================
Total params: 891,713
Trainable params: 891,713
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Also when I fit model the result is as below:

```
Train on 15663 samples, validate on 3916 samples
Epoch 1/30
15663/15663 [==============================] - 92s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6338 - acc: 0.6667 - val_loss: 0.6318 - val_acc: 0.6667
Epoch 2/30
15663/15663 [==============================] - 93s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6331 - acc: 0.6666 - val_loss: 0.6317 - val_acc: 0.6667
Epoch 3/30
15663/15663 [==============================] - 92s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6326 - acc: 0.6667 - val_loss: 0.6318 - val_acc: 0.6667
Epoch 4/30
15663/15663 [==============================] - 92s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6327 - acc: 0.6667 - val_loss: 0.6315 - val_acc: 0.6667
Epoch 5/30
15663/15663 [==============================] - 91s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6321 - acc: 0.6667 - val_loss: 0.6316 - val_acc: 0.6667
Epoch 6/30
15663/15663 [==============================] - 94s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6321 - acc: 0.6667 - val_loss: 0.6316 - val_acc: 0.6667
Epoch 7/30
15663/15663 [==============================] - 91s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6320 - acc: 0.6667 - val_loss: 0.6316 - val_acc: 0.6667
Epoch 8/30
15663/15663 [==============================] - 92s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6321 - acc: 0.6667 - val_loss: 0.6318 - val_acc: 0.6667
Epoch 9/30
15610/15663 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6318 - acc: 0.6667
```

Comment: `train_sentence` and `evalu` are not defined

Comment: thank you I deleted them here, we don't need it in this code.i hope you can help me.

Comment: Try a simpler model to see what your baseline is.

Comment: I am very new to deep learning can you please help me..im getting lost

Comment: now I also pre trained with glove and my accuracy .. decreased..,

Comment: Your code does not run as it is, try to reduce it to a simple, runnable script, so we can reproduce your error

Comment: i dont think you should add a dropout layer right after the embedding layer